# Can views be returned without a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

with site structure as below

[image: site structure]

and route config as

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Then I go to `http://localhost:23233`, it shows me with index.cshtml in root, if i rename the root index.cshtml, it shows me index in views/home folder. I do not quite understand this. Aren't all views returned by controller? can someone explain this to me?

Comment: I am intrigued. As far as I know, you have to specifically ignore root (`""`) requests have MVC ignore it and have it pick up the index through the regular asp.net system. Maybe you could elaborate, is the `HomeController` being hit at all? Or is the view called directly (as if it were an old fashioned asp.net aspx page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/Index.cshtml` is a standalone Web Page, it doesn't need a controller. You can disable Web Pages using the following setting on Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't seen this before but index.cshtml and default.cshtml in the root your application will be treated as index.html and default.html used to be treated in older asp.net applications.  Makes sense for folk migrating to mvc from asp.net I guess.

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1577234.aspx/1